# BUKKIT PLUGIN API: How can I check if a player's inventory contains an item included in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, bukkit, inventory

I am making a **Bukkit** plugin in Java called *BanItems*. I have multiple problems with creating it, and I just cannot find an answer ANYWHERE. So I asked this question.
In the code, **I have an array, ItemsBanned[ ]**, and only includes Strings.
I wanted to check and see if any player has an item in their inventory that is in that array.

```
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    Inventory inv = player.getInventory();


    if (inv.contains(itemsBanned[x])) {

     }
```

For some odd reason, when I copy & paste the code here, it totally jacks up no matter what I do with the 4 spaces and stuff like that. So, that is all I can show.

It won't let me see if a player's inventory contains an item from the array itemsBanned.
How can I do that?
Please answer.

Comment: Not that it has anything to do with the code, but spacing really has nothing to do with coding when you're working with Java. It just makes it look nicer

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple for loop. I'm going to assume from your question that ItemsBanned are names of items.

```
for(int i = 0; i < itemsBanned.length(); i++){
    Material m = Material.getMaterial(itemsBanned[i]); //convert the strings to Materials
    if(inv.contains(m)){
        //do something here
    }
}
```

The only problem with that code is that you can't remove the items, you can only be alerted if the player has one, or more of the items. If you would like to remove the banned items, you could do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < itemsBanned.length(); i++){
    Material m = Material.getMaterial(itemsBanned[i]); //convert the strings to Materials

    for(int n = 0; n < inv.getSize(); n++){ //loop threw all items in the inventory
        ItemStack itm = inv.getItem(n); //get the items
        if(itm != null){ //make sure the item is not null, or you'll get a NullPointerException
            if(itm.getType().equals(m)){ //if the item equals a contraband item
                inv.remove(m); //remove the item
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know how to check ALL the player's inventories at once. Only onPlayerJoin() I can.

Comment: You could get all the online players with `for(Player p: Bukkit.getServer().getOnlinePlayers()){` then just do `inv = p.getInventory();`